# Message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an app that navigates thru different views using the navigation controller. This is what I’m doing:

```
MapViewController *aMap = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapView" 
                                                              bundle:nil ];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aMap 
                                     animated:YES];
[aMap release];
```

At an user action, I want to go back to the first view. This is what I did:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView 
 didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

When I press a button that call the bellow method, my app goes as expected to the first view. But the problem arises when I press the “Home button” and try to reopen the app. Then, the app crash giving the following error:

```
2010-12-23 14:33:18.504 test[4549:307] *** -[MapViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5c26320
```

I understand that I sending a message to an instance of the object that does not exist, but I don’t find where is this happening

Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: Please correctly format your question, makes reading it easier

Comment: Use the debug mode and it will stop at the exact line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something is trying to send messages to the MapViewController after it's been deallocated.

Are they any objects that reference it - is it the delegate for any of its subviews, or does it receive any notifications, or anything like that?

If so, you need to make sure you unsubscribe from any notifications in the controller's `dealloc` method, and set any `delegate` parameters (on other objects) that reference the controller to nil.

Comment: thank you so much for this, it really saved my life! and I had a problem with the self.navigationController.delegate that was delegated in multiple viewControllers and never setted to nil, that was driving me insane for days :) thaks a lot!

Comment: What happens when a method on a thread started before unsubscribing from a notification and continues after class as been deallocated?

Comment: Thank you, it was OK. I set a delegate for a singleton method for location that was still trying to update its position to its delegate class that didn't exist. So in viewWillDisappear I had to set singleton's delegate to nil.